# Is it possible to issue compile error if object is stack created (including inherited types)?

Tags: c++, c++17, factory

Basically I want all sub-types to be created through a factory method (I have a tall domain hierarchy with some 200+ classes).

For `new`, it is not an issue since this can be overridden in A (making `new` private).

```
class A{
protected:
  A();
public:
  template<class T, typename... ARGUMENTS>
  static T* create(ARGUMENTS&&... arguments);
};

class B : public A {
public:
  B();
};

void test() {
  B b;//compile error wanted here - but as a consequence of inheriting A
}
```

Here A is a the "library/framework" class. Whereas B is a "user created class". It might be ok to require a typedef or similar on B.

UPDATE: I added the 'create' function on A that I intent to use for creating objects.

Comment: Off-topic, but it isn't really possible with `new` either. Because one can simply use `::new A`.

Comment: This lo problem, don't fall for that! Anyhow, you can make the constructor private and only supply a factory function that allocates the object dynamically.

Comment: @jcarpenter2 I added create method to A - basicly it forwards its arguments to constructor and does something more.

Comment: Can we modify `B` ?

Comment: @Jarod42 yes and no. A is a the "library/framework class" and B/inherited is "user created classes". But a required typedef on B for example is OK.

Comment: Why do you want to prohibit stack object ?

Comment: @Jarod42 in order to store, on A, some most derived type dependent information. But that is sort of off topic.

Comment: So modifications to `B` are admissible as long as the program doesn't compile without them?  I.e. so you can know for certain that no subclasses of `A` are stack-allocated once the program compiles?

Comment: Can `B` use CRTP and private constructors ?

Comment: @jcarpenter2 yes, those would be fine.

Comment: @Jarod42 CRTP will not work well in this case for a few reasons. One is that it will explode typewise since the heirachy is tall.

Comment: My question about usage was to know if it is not a XY problem. One case I see where solution might be forcing new is to have fixed address (for registration as signal/slot of Qt), but then prohibiting `move` is "sufficient".

Comment: What if you have a static method "make_class" in your derived classes and use it in your base class "create"? Then you can make you derived class constructor private.

Comment: @Ashkan that might work. But im still left with issue that its not 'forced'. Users can still make constructor public and create object (on stack).

Comment: Yeah I thought about that as well. 
I am just speculating here since at the moment I don't have time to try this but here I go:
You could try the Curiously recurring template pattern which forces the programmer to pass their class as the template argument to the base class. 
That way you could check in your base class if they have the function or not and also put maybe some sort of checks in you base class. I am thinking of runtime check like if you can initialize the derived class then raise an error.

Comment: Actually that wouldn't work I think but I let the comment be maybe it helps some of the users here to a better answer.

Comment: @Ashkan indeed, I suspect CRTP here will be a 'mess' and ruining some dynamic_casting etc. :( since the heirachy is tall.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can require a token in the construction of `A` that is only passed in the body of `A::create`

```
#include <utility>

class A{
private:
  struct create_token
  { 
    create_token(const create_token &) = delete; 
    create_token& operator=(const create_token &) = delete; 
    create_token(create_token &&) = default; 
    create_token& operator=(create_token &&) = default; 
  };
protected:
  A(create_token) {}
public:
  template<class T, typename... ARGUMENTS>
  static T* create(ARGUMENTS&&... arguments)
  {
    // Whatever creation mechanism here
    return new T(create_token{}, std::forward<ARGUMENTS>(arguments)...);
  }
};

class B : public A {
public:
  template <typename Token> // Can't name A::create_token, it is private
  B(Token tok) : A(std::move(tok)) {}
  B(){} // Will always lack a `create_token`
};

int main() {
  B b;//compile error wanted here - but as a consequence of inheriting A
  B* b = A::create<B>();
}
```

[See it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d82d39e6c3b689a9)

Comment: This is actually a really good and sound solution ! The only drawback for me is it will take me some time to update everything.

Comment: @darune You might use fancy mechanism like CRPT to get  `create` and `create_token` generic

Comment: @R2RT I don't think that's the effort, instead it's all the `template <typename Token> B::B(Token tok)` changes. I am also wary of suggesting *more* inheritance here

Answer (score 1):

This is another approach which relies on checking if the derived class constructor is private. But honestly, I prefer the solution given by @Caleth

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>


template<typename T, typename... Args>
struct constructor_tag{};



class A{
protected:


    template<typename T, typename... Args>
    A(constructor_tag<T, Args...>) {
        static_assert(!std::is_constructible_v<T, Args...>, "CONSTRUCTOR MUST NOT BE PUBLIC");
    };


public:
    template<class T, typename... ARGUMENTS>
    static T* create(ARGUMENTS&&... arguments) {
        return new T(std::forward<ARGUMENTS>(arguments)...);
    }
};

class B : public A {

    friend class A;
    B() : A(constructor_tag<B>{}) {}
public:
};

class C : public A {
    friend class A;

    C () : A(constructor_tag<C>{}) {}

    C(int) : A(constructor_tag<C, int>{}) {}
public:

};


// Following class will not compile because the constructor is public

//class D : public A {
//    friend class A;
//
//public:
//    D () : A(constructor_tag<D>{}) {}
//
//};

void test() {

    // B b; //calling a private constructor of class 'B'
    // C c(5);//calling a private constructor of class 'A'

    A::create<B>();
    A::create<C>(5);
    A::create<C>();
}

int main() {


    test();
}
```

Comment: Even if @Caleth solution is cleaner there may be some value that can be extracted from this. If there is a way to check in the general case that a type has no public constructor or failing that if the destructor is protected - then that could just save some time implemententing as I already have a way of sorts of enumerating all the types (or can just check in the relevant cases).